# Child object data binding in Grails controller

Tags: javascript, grails

I am trying to setup a javascript object such that when it data binds to a new object in the controller, the associated child objects in the DB are pulled based on the id field. This is documented in the Spring data binding as such:

> Data binding and Associations
>
> If you have a one-to-one or many-to-one association you can use
>   Grails' data binding capability to update these relationships too. For
>   example if you have an incoming request such as:
>
> /book/save?author.id=20
>
> Grails will automatically detect the .id suffix on the request
>   parameter and look-up the Author instance for the given id when doing
>   data binding such as:
>
> def b = new Book(params)

I want to post a javascript object to the controller as a fully composed object with the child properties. How can I setup the javascript object so that the controller sees the child properties of the object as in the following url (the same as is documented)  /book/save?author.id=20?

I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
var childObject= function(name, id) {
                this.name = name;
                this.id = id;    
            };

var viewModel = {
    id: 1,
    child: new childObject("Chuck",1)
 }
```

The controller doesn't see 'child.id' when the viewModel is posted to the controller and automatically fetch the associated record. Am I totally off base thinking it works like this?

Perhaps another way to ask this is how can I serialize a javascript object so that its string representation is "object.property"?

Comment: Could you add your Domain objects to your code?
Also, could you add a println(params) at the beginning of the closure that you're hitting in the controller so we can see what data you are passing to Grails? That would help quite a bit to give you an answer

Answer (score 0):

Creating the javascript object as {child :{id:1} }  should do what you are trying to achieve.  Try something like this to create the required js object

```
     var dataObj = {};
     var childObj = {};
     childObj['id'] = 1;
     dataObj['child'] =  childObj;
     return dataObj;
```

Comment: The grails controller 'sees' this construct as childObj[id] and not the intended childObj.id. This is the same result I had with my example.